# How do I echo an inner join column name

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables that I have inner joined called milk and jan both has a column named id. trying to make a modal popup, but it wouldn't work bc of the ambigous id column name so i tried milk.id but still wouldn't work. is there a way around it?

this is my php query:

```
$sql="SELECT milk.pemohon, milk.nokp, milk.keterangan, jan.status 
FROM milk 
INNER JOIN jan ON milk.id = jan.users_id";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    ?>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Pemohon</th>
          <th>No. KP</th>
          <th>Keterangan</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Penghantaran</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $row["pemohon"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row["nokp"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row["keterangan"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row["status"]; ?></td>
          <td><button data-id='<?php echo $row['milk.id']; ?>' class="userinfo btn btn-success">Info</button></td>
        </tr>
        <?php  
          }
        }  
        ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Do a var_dump or print_r of the contents of $row, then you will know what the actual keys in there are. And/or go read up on what an _Alias_ inside an SQL query is & does.

Comment: `milk.id` doesn't exist into your `DB` and doesn't exist in your select query. you must add it into query like `SELECT milk.id` then use like `echo $row['id']`

Comment: Sidenote: Why `ajax` tag ??

Comment: Sorry i didn't realize i added the ajax tag. I will try the alias advice @CBroe thanks. I have already tried to insert the select milk.id as well, didn't work but thank you for the advice

Comment: Have a look at column aliases - `milk.id as mid` etc.

Comment: I just tried it, but didn't work either, my modal is still empty once I click the button

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql="
SELECT 
    milk.id AS milk_id, 
    milk.pemohon, 
    milk.nokp, 
    milk.keterangan,
    jan.id AS jan_id, 
    jan.status 
FROM milk 
INNER JOIN jan ON milk.id = jan.users_id
";
```

Now you can just select milk_id or jan_id in php using `$row['milk_id']` or `$row['jan_id']`

To explain:
MySQL uses the column name as name, thus on `milk.id` it uses `id`.
If you have multiple select with the same column name, ex `milk.id` and `jan.id` it returns `id` and `id(1)` respectively.
Best thing is to use an alias with `AS`  followed by the name. In this way, MySQL returns that as the name.